# HTML Agility Pack - Get div without class or id (C#)

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I've been trying to follow some solutions here on StackOverflow but I need some help.
This is the source HTML:

```
<div class="myclass">
 <div style="font-size:2em;"> STRING_N1 </div>
 <div> STRING_N2 </div>
</div>
```

And this is my current code:

```
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlcode);
        var res = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myclass']");
        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            var firstDiv = item.SelectSingleNode("div");
            var content1 = firstDiv.ChildNodes[0].InnerText.Trim();
            richTextBox1.AppendText(content1.ToString());
        }
```

So far so good, I can extract "**STRING_N1**" without a problem. However, I can't figure it out on how to extract **STRING_N2** without having a class or id.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` to get descendant `div`s:

```
var divs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myclass']") 
              .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants("div"));

var contents = divs.Select(x => x.InnerText.Trim());

richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, contents);
```